# is it possible to set up drag/drop tabview tabs in qooxdoo?

Tags: drag-and-drop, qooxdoo

I would like to allow re-ordering of tabs in a tabview, preferrably using drag and drop of the tab buttons.  The example drag/drop code for lists, modified for tabs simply doesn't work (the dragstart event is never fired).

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1):

At the moment we do not have this functionality out-of-the-box available. However, you can create a bug report at [your bugzilla](http://bugzilla.qooxdoo.org) to get this feature in a future release.